# ODE for The folium of Descartes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

The folium of Descartes:
Given the function $F(x, y)= x^3+y^3-3xy$, the set $L={ \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: F(x,y)=0} \}$ and $q_0=(x_0,y_0)=(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2})\in M$, how can I find an ordinary differential equation together with the initial condition.

My idea: first implicitly differentiate the given equation.

Result: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y-x^2}{y^2-2x}$. Is that correct? What is the next step?

Comment: Where did those $2$s come from?

Comment: $x^3+y^3-3xy=0 \implies 3x^2+ 3y^2 dy/dx= 6x dy/dx + 6y \implies 3y^2 dy/dx−6x dy/dx= 6y−3x^2 \implies dy/dx  (3y^2−6x) = 6y−3x^2 \implies dy/dx=\frac {6y−3x^2}{3y^2−6}$

Comment: Those 6s should be 3s. You got them by differentiating $3xy$ and the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

As Jyrki noted in a comment, you have the right idea, but the correct DE is
$$y'(x)=\frac{x^2-y}{x-y^2}. $$
As for an initial condition, just use $y(3/2)=3/2:$ the point on the folium. At this point, I'd say you were done.